# Does ng-disabled work in div tag? if no, then why?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have tried using ng-disabled in div tag, but it is not working. does ng-disabled will work on div tags? if yes then how?

```
<div ng-disabled="true">
 <button>bbb</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

"ng-disabled" just adds or removes the "disabled" attribute on the element.
However in HTML "disabled" on a div has no effect at all.

So in a way "ng-disabled" is working, but it just does not make sense to use it on a div.

You can add "ng-disabled" to a fieldset though which will make input elements nested in it appear disabled.

Another workaround might be to simulate the disabled effect by using css properties "opacity" and "pointer-events: none", see http://nerd.vasilis.nl/disable-html-elements-with-css-only/

Comment: In regards to adding the css effects, if you're using bootstrap -- it already does this for buttons. You could easily add your own css styling though:  http://plnkr.co/edit/nmBmfKC7a56iDmupqh7Z?p=preview

Comment: Nothing mentions that `ng-disabled` is applicable to a `fieldset` tag, so this answer is incredibly valuable!

Answer (score 5):

there is a number of elements in HTML that takes the 'disabled' attribute in effect,
DIV is not one of them.

you can see what elements take that attribute, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html)

these elements accept the 'disabled' attr:

- button
- input
- select
- textarea
- optgroup
- option
- fieldset

Answer (score 4):

you can use the next directive:

//***********************************//
//this directive is ng-disabled directive for all elements and not only for button
//***********************************//

```
app.directive('disabledElement', function () {
    return {
       restrict: 'A', 
        scope: {
            disabled: '@'

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.disabledElement, function (newVal) {

                if (newVal)
                    $(element).css('pointerEvents', 'none');


                else
                    $(element).css('pointerEvents', 'all');


            });

        }

    }
});
```

and the html:

```
 <div ng-click="PreviewMobile()" data-disabled-element="toolbar_lock"></div>
```

Comment: try add `-webkit-touch-callout: none`

Answer (score 1):

The usage of 'ng-disabled', as the dev guide of angular says, is only for an input tag.

```
<INPUT ng-disabled="">
 ...
</INPUT>
```

Comment: input is a self closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I gather, you are trying to disable the div when the button is pushed? Otherwise you can just disable the button like this.

```
<div>
 <button ng-disabled="true">bbb</button>
</div>
```

But I don't understand why because it cannot be enabled again.